# Set up generalized regression neural network with 2D target value matrix y. Translating Matlab's newgrnn to python

Tags: python, matlab, neural-network, regression

Could anyone offer advice on setting up a radial basis network with an Nx3 matrix of input vectors and an Nx3 target class matrix? In every example I have found the target class matrix must be a 1D array, which is not in a format useful for me.

I am trying to translate code written in Matlab to Python, and am running into an issue trying to find a Python equivalent for the [newgrnn function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/newgrnn.html) . Here is an excerpt of the matlab code I'm working on translating:

```
smooth = 0.1
model = newgrnn(all_points', all_vectors', smooth);

deform_vector = sim(model, source_nodes');
```

The shapes/info of these variables are as follows:

```
all_points' = 3x13780
all_vectors' = 3x13780
deform_vector = 3x13780


model info:    
numInputs: 1
numLayers: 2
numOutputs: 1
numWeightElements: 96460
```

What I have tried in python (and the errors I run into)

USING [pyGRNN](https://github.com/federhub/pyGRNN)

```
from pyGRNN import GRNN
from sklearn.model_selection import  GridSearchCV

IGRNN = GRNN()
params_IGRNN = {'kernel':["RBF"],
       'sigma' : [0.1],
       'calibration' : ['None']
        }
            
grid_IGRNN = GridSearchCV(estimator=IGRNN,
                 param_grid=params_IGRNN,
                 scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                 cv=5,
                 verbose=1
                 )
            
grid_IGRNN.fit(all_points, all_vectors)
best_model = grid_IGRNN.best_estimator_
deform_vectors = best_model.predict(np.tranpose(source_nodes))
```

The error from this:

```
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (13780, 3) instead.
```

USING [NeuPy](http://neupy.com/apidocs/neupy.algorithms.rbfn.grnn.html)

```
from neupy import algorithms

nw = algorithms.GRNN(std = 0.1, verbose = False)
nw.train(all_points, all_vectors)
```

The error from this:

```
ValueError: Target value must be one dimensional array
```

I would be grateful for any insight anyone might have. Please let me know if more information is needed.